# How to handle the Unicode Attack for a web site?

Tags: web, character-encoding, rendering

Strange Unicode text is able to broke rendering of the whole web site. I can't put this text directly, because it can damage rendering (see screenshot below).

I will put the code of the attack text. It is array of 125 characters with the following 16-bit integer values:

```
[3626, 3655, 3655,..., 3655]
```

I called it `The Unicode Attack` - a new generation of attacks in Web. If you put this text in comments or somewhere else on a web site, a browser will render a horrible line on the screen.

To solve this problem I can put some characters and texts that can damage a web site in a black list, but I'm afraid that the list will become too large, so I don't know how to prevent this error.

I'm looking for an elegant solution for this problem. I want to be able to prevent such attacks.

[image]

Comment: That isn't a single character; it's 125 characters

Comment: Yes, you are right, it looks like a character but this is a text. Only MsWord display it correct, other programs not.

Comment: post it on pastebin, please

Comment: @FLCL I added screenshot in my post, please review. I posted this text on pastebin, the link is http://pastebin.com/nqGZsGxJ

Comment: @FLCL I posted this text again and now it damages rendering :( http://pastebin.com/3QeR7kBU

Comment: This is called ["Zalgo text" and I've posted a question on how it can be blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277052/how-can-zalgo-text-be-prevented) (which this question is a duplicate of). My question has received some answers already.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thanks, this is a good news, because I have no idea what can I do with this text.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that kind of bad-displayed characters is the same thing as, for example, bad words, spam or any other useless text, which should be removed by moderators. Also, probably [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) can help you.